# Perform multiple sequelize query with multiple threads

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am currently performing all queries one by one with await so all data is fetched before res.send(),

```
    var classes = await Classes.findAll({ where: { isActive: 'Y' } })
    var users = await Users.findAll({ where: { isActive: 'Y' } })
    var calender = await Calender.findAll({ where: { isActive: 'Y' } })

    res.status(500).send({classes, users, calender})
```

What I want is, each query is executed by different thread and wait before res.send() so execution time can be saved.

I am confident that there is a better solution that uses Sequelize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't precisely the same as multi-threading, the solution you are looking for is concurrent queries that are executed asynchronously. This is really the best solution for any async I/O where the results are not dependent on each other.

Use `Promise.all()` to resolve all of the queries at the same time. You can use an array deconstructor to fetch each value that is returned from each promise.

It's also preferable to use `const` instead of `var` when the value of the variable will not change.

```js
const where = { isActive: 'Y' };

const [ classes, users, calender ] = await Promise.all([
  Classes.findAll({ where }),
  Users.findAll({ where }),
  Calender.findAll({ where }),
]);

res.status(500).send({classes, users, calender});
```

*note - you have a typo as well, "calender" should be "calendar"*

Comment: @FareedMurtaza if this answer works for you can you mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: @doublesharp Would you know whether your solution is supposed to work even if the queries are part of the same transaction?

Comment: @Kal as long as you create the transaction first and then pass it in to each of the queries it will work, but you need to consider how you handle rollbacks and commits (you dont want to use an already rolled back transaction).